# How to prevent the License Management App (LMA) from creating Lead records when a package is installed via an installation URL?

Tags: managed-package, leads, insert, lma, install

#### Is it possible to prevent Lead records from being created by the License Management App (LMA) when a package is installed via an installation URL?

If package installation occurs via an installation URL, then the License Management App (LMA) will create a Lead with the Lead Source of "**Package Installation**."

Is there an option to prevent the Leads from being created, or should some sort of custom development be used (i.e. like a `before insert` trigger)? What is recommended in this scenario?

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/lma_terms_relationships.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are [specifically warned](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/lma_troubleshoot_no_leads_licenses.htm) not to cause errors on the Lead, specially in a Before DML trigger.

> Don’t use before_create or before_update triggers on leads and licenses. Instead, use after_ triggers, or remove all triggers. If a trigger fails, it can block license creation.

Instead, if you really want to remove the record, you can do so asynchronously via Future method, Asynchronous Flow, etc.